# How can extract multiple email id's and phone numbers from a single text file with python?

Tags: python, json, text

Hello i have a large text file containing multiple information. I'd like to extract only e-mail id and phone numbers with a python program or a tool.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"id":"269","first_name":"N S","last_name":"","balance":"0","phonecode":null,"mobile":null,"email":"wand412@gmail.com","verified":"0","password":""}


HTTP/1.1 200 OK


{"id":"303","first_name":"Devi","last_name":"Baruah","balance":"0","phonecode":null,"mobile":null,"email":"dxxxxxx@yahoo.com","verified":"0","password":""}


HTTP/1.1 200 OK


{"id":"306","first_name":"Rashmi","last_name":"Kumari","balance":"24","phonecode":"91","mobile":"9xxxxxxx","email":"xxxxxxx7@gmail.com","verified":"1","password":"xxxx"}


HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"id":"308","first_name":"ashwini","last_name":"gokhale","balance":"7","phonecode":"1","mobile":"61xxxx","email":"axxxx@gmail.com","verified":"1","password":"xxxxxxx"}


HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"id":"307","first_name":"Rama","last_name":"De","balance":"0","phonecode":"91","mobile":"73xxxxxx","email":"dexxxx@gmail.com","verified":"1","password":"xxxx"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that is a log from a webserver. If possible try have a cleaner file in first,
anyhow:

```
import json

mandatory_keys = ['email', 'mobile']
file_str = []
out = []
with open('test') as fd:
    file_str = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in fd.readlines() if x.startswith('{')]
for j_str in file_str:
    try:
        j = json.loads(j_str)
        assert [x for x in mandatory_keys if x in j.keys()] == mandatory_keys, f'missing mandatory_keys'
        out.append({k: v for k, v in j.items() if k in mandatory_keys})
    except:
        raise ValueError('Something wrong with the json')
    
print(out)
```

Also you may want to use some json model validator as 'jsonschema' to substitute the assert line there and have a clear error message.
Changing the mandatory_key list you can easily update you outpu.

Comment: the code is very well written, however, I just want the data within the email and mobile, how can I do that? besides from that I must say the code works perfectly

Comment: The out dict do the work to filter the data, from that you can print as you like: 
csv: f"{out['mobile']; out['email']}", just print: f"{out['mobile']  out['email']}", sql: f"{insert into tab select out['mobile'], out['email']}" ..

Answer (score 0):

If your file is named `test.txt`, you can use the below snippet to parse the json parts from the file, one line at a time:

```
import json


items = []
with open("test.txt") as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        try:
            if item := json.loads(line):
                items.append(item)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass

# 'items' is a list of dictionaries that contain each user's details.
# If you want to extract the IDs, email addresses and phone numbers into separate lists, one way to do it is:
ids = [item.get("id") for item in items]
email = [item.get("email") for item in items]
mobile = [item.get("mobile") for item in items]
```

Comment: i seem to get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iamun\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    ids = [int(item.get("id")) for item in items]
  File "C:\Users\iamun\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    ids = [int(item.get("id")) for item in items]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: i get several output lines with none

Comment: Good catch, there's at least one line that gets parsed as `None`. I've updated the code such that it skips any `None`s. I used the walrus operator, so if you use a python version less than 3.8, you need to replace `if item := json.loads(line):` with the old syntax.

Comment: wait i think i'm getting the error coz  some data is null instead of json file